# Test Failed 'Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)' when loading Accounts with Test.LoadData

Tags: apex, unit-test, person-accounts, test-data, test.loaddata

**Background**

When I use the `Test.LoadData` method to load Account records:

```
List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>) Test.loadData(Account.sObjectType, 'account_test_data');
```

I get this error message:

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)

Even though there are no validation rules on the Account object.

The data is stored in a static resource with contentType of `text/csv`

```
FirstName,LastName,Phone,PersonHomePhone,PersonMobilePhone,RecordTypeId
Gary,Green,,07970 123 123,,0120O0000003bewQAA
```

And the debug log abruptly ends like this:

> 13:08:57.2 (3439995)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|Test.Test()
>   13:08:57.2 (3445692)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
>   13:08:57.2 (3469949)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|Test
>   13:08:57.2 (3494129)|METHOD_ENTRY|[5]||System.Test.loadData(Schema.SObjectType, String)

But when I create an Account using code:

```
Account a = new Account();
a.FirstName = 'Gary';
a.LastName = 'Green';
a.Phone = '';
a.PersonHomePhone = '07970 123 123';
a.PersonMobilePhone = '';
a.RecordTypeId = Id.valueOf('0120O0000003bewQAA');
insert a;
```

It works fine.

**Question**

Why am I getting the validation error when using `Test.LoadData` ?

Comment: I tried same code, got same error...

Comment: Do you have any other records that would be created as a result of creating an Account record?  Do you receive the same validation error if you try and create an account with the same details through the UI manually? What is the validation error you are receiving?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, the running user a System Administrator with access to the Record Type. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Tad I do **not** get the same message when creating the Account manually via code, only via `Test.LoadData`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks for validating the issue. Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: Set your debug logs as high as they go (FINEST for all categories) in the Developer Console, run the tests from the Developer Console, you should see the validation errors in the logs from the test run.

Comment: @sfdcfox i replicated it in newly created scratch org, It works via anon window and does work when i use loadData in test. Could be a bug, Robs if you have premium support can you raise it with Salesforce Support team?

Comment: can you please add one more column for `Name` in csv and provide the value for that. Then try to load data. I believe you are creating a business account?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Could you generate a log and see what the error was?

Comment: @sfdcfox when I run the test via the developer console (rather than vscode) the log ends with this line `19:37:19:278 METHOD_ENTRY [22]|System.Test.loadData(Schema.SObjectType, String)`

Comment: @Robs, have you tried with adding `Name` field?

Comment: @PragatiJain yes, just tried and got the same error `Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)`

Comment: @sfdcfox here is the GIST : https://gist.github.com/pranayjswl007/d817ef256a93751003918f861d9df45f

Comment: @sfdcfox any thoughts on what I should do about this? :)

Comment: @Robs what kind of org are you doing this in? I don't have time to set up a scratch org at the moment, but I can play with it tonight. The test passes in my dev org and one sandbox I tried in, so it's something different. I don't have any other ideas that we haven't already gone over.

Comment: @sfdcfox it was failing against a Developer sandbox org

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but changing the RecordTypeId value in your csv file to 15 characters instead of 18 makes it work.

```
0120O0000003bewQAA ===> 0120O0000003bew
```

Comment: No idea why, but this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a limitation with `Test.LoadData` in support for Person Accounts when attempting to set the RecordTypeId. This results in the error message:

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)

If you do raise a support case for this it should reference back to W-7298675